# Move a range of elements between containers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, move, move-semantics

I've been looking at the C++ documentation for a function which would move a range of elements from one container to another, using move semantics. However, I have not found such a function. What am I missing?

How would I do the following without copying and using explicit loops?

```
// Move 10 elements from beginning of source to end of dest
dest.end() <- move(source.begin(), source.begin() + 10)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `std::move` in `<algorithm>`:

```
std::move(source.begin(), source.begin() + 10,
            std::insert_iterator(dest, dest.end()));
```

It's just like `std::copy`, except it move-assigns instead of copy-assigns.

Comment: Where can I find a reference documentation for that function? I've been googling and looking at the C++0x final draft... can't seem to find it.

Comment: @ronag: I looked at §25.3.2, in n3126.

Comment: Just adding that in MSVS-2010, <algorithm> does not automatically include <iterator> anymore.